# Magento 2 edit my-account-link element content?

Tags: magento2, link

I'm using magento 2, and I'm trying to edit the my-account-link element , the one that writes My Account in the top bar , I just want to change the text with an icon , what's the html or phtml file to edit it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit my-account-link from xml file only.
For this No phtml file is generated that comes from xml file.

XML File Path for my-account-link,

**`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`**

You can update it using **default.xml** file

```
 <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Custom Link Name</argument>
        </arguments>
  </block>
```

Remove cache and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi. you can replace that text with image through phtml file.
for this, you can enable the template path hints. then you will find the path for that easily.
Not only for this, you can find the path for anything on your website to edit by enabled the path hints.

Comment: I have tryed to do so , but couldn't find the right file..

Comment: Actually. i dont know in magento2. I changed that in magento-1.9.2.2 at /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout